# Is there any possible using CompositeDisposable lead to OOM?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

**CompositeDisposable: A disposable container that can hold onto multiple other disposables and offers O(1) add and removal complexity.**

In some situation, I would create many **one-shot observable** to do some time-consuming jobs.Every time a observable-subscriber has been create, a disposable will be create and add into this 'container'.

Finally when you quit the Activity or some scenario, this 'container' can be `clear()` or `dispose()`, remove all the disposable whatever they are finished or not.

So my question is, can I delete the specific, **already finished totally subscriber** to avoid the **size** of the 'container' increase unlimitedly before I quit the current activity?

**update:**
remove the observer from container when `onComplete` or `onDispose` maybe achieve this target, but is there any convenient solution?

Comment: You'd have to remember the consumer and remove it at the right time. There is an extension feature that helps you do this: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#subscribeautorelease

Comment: @akarnokd I can use this extension feature or implement a Observer myself. But I need to change all Rx usage before. It seem to be to 'heavy'.

Comment: There is no lighter way with the standard RxJava toolset, you'll have to code and replace usages all over the place.